# Look up a value using month of the date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table like below.

I want to have a cell where I can get the number depending on the current month.

For example, today is 31/3/2024. I would like the cell to be 4

Tomorrow when it is 1/4/2024. I would like it to automatically update to 3425

I don't want to use app script

| Date | Number |
| --- | --- |
| 3/2024 | 4 |
| 4/2024 | 3425 |
| 5/2024 | 6 |
| 6/2024 | 8 |
| 7/2024 | 456 |
| 8/2024 | 2343 |
| 9/2024 | 1234534 |
| 10/2024 | 546 |
| 11/2024 | 6 |
| 12/2024 | 234 |
| 1/2025 | 5634 |
| 2/2025 | 3454 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if data in ***Column A*** is true date then use-

```
=FILTER(B2:B,A2:A>=EOMONTH(D2,-1)+1,A2:A<=EOMONTH(D2,0))
=FILTER(B2:B,A2:A>=EOMONTH(E2,-1)+1,A2:A<=EOMONTH(E2,0))
```

If you don't want to use cell reference then direct use `TODAY()` function inside formula so that it changes everyday.

```
=FILTER(B2:B,A2:A>=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1,A2:A<=EOMONTH(TODAY(),0))
```

And if the values are just text string in ***Column A*** then could use-

```
=FILTER(B2:B,MAP(A2:A,LAMBDA(x,IF(x="",,INDEX(SPLIT(x,"/"),1))))=MONTH(TODAY()))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After you put the list in your question in A:B, and set the target dates (or date strings) in D2:D, you may want to use the formula like what I wrote below:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(D2:D<>"", 
    FILTER(B2:B, 
      (YEAR(DATEVALUE(A2:A))=YEAR(DATEVALUE(D2:D))) 
      *
      (MONTH(DATEVALUE(A2:A))=MONTH(DATEVALUE(D2:D)))
    ),
  )
)
```

The keys are

1. [`DATEVALUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039) to cast strings into date values, so that you can use
2. [`YEAR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093061) and [`MONTH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093052) to extract the year and the month of both the list and the targets alternatively.

However, the solution provided above is correct only in the scenario where you do not have any target out of the range of list. If the scenario is in the case, you may want to use the revised version below:

```
=MAP(D2:D, 
  LAMBDA(target, 
    IF(target<>"", 
      IFERROR(FILTER(B2:B, 
        (YEAR(DATEVALUE(A2:A))=YEAR(DATEVALUE(target)))
          *
        (MONTH(DATEVALUE(A2:A))=MONTH(DATEVALUE(target)))
      ), ""),
 "")))
```

Demo is noted here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HcL1ZFJ-26HU9lZVKJufE63cSDCOtVWYXOAqwnJPn40/edit#gid=0